# In what order should I play the Dragon Age DLC?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-origins-awakening

I want to finish up playing through Dragon Age: Origins - Awakening and the DLC before Dragon Age 2 comes out. I already have *The Stone Prisoner*, *Warden's Keep*, and *Return to Ostagar*.

In what order should I play Awakening and the post-release DLC if I want to experience the story in chronological order? For example, is *Witch Hunt* before or after Awakening and/or when does *The Golems of Amgarrak* take place?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I recommend the following order:

1. Origins (Warden's Keep, Return to Ostagar, Stone Prisoner in any order)
2. Leliana's Song (Chronologically this is before Origins, but it reveals background for an Origins character, so do it after you have spoken to Leliana extensively.)
3. Awakening
4. Golems of Angarrak
5. Witch Hunt

You can do Darkspawn Chronicles any time after Origins, it's an alternate ending, just for fun.

Comment: Note also that Golems is *much* harder than any of the other DLCs, and is not directly relevant to the plot (although it does contain a significant amount of dwarven backstory which may be of interest to serious players).  If you can't kill the boss at the end, I would skip to Witch Hunt.